# XSRF token expired after website publish to IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I am using ASP.NET Boilerplate framework, I put the below code in everypage.

```
@inject IAbpAntiForgeryManager AbpAntiForgeryManager

@{
    AbpAntiForgeryManager.SetCookie(Context);
}
```

I call the app service as below:

```
var xhr = abp.services.app.order.add(data);

        xhr.done(function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
```

Everything works fine when I run in localhost, XSRF token will not expired even if I rebuild the project. Every time when I click [Publish website to IIS], all the ajax request will return 400 Bad Request, I guess it is because the XSRF token has expired, everything back to normal after I click F5 in browser. It was so annoying for the user, any thing I can do to prevent this error? Or auto refresh token?

Thank you!

### update

error message in LOG file:

```
ERROR 2019-02-12 13:40:09,773 [71   ] .Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery - An exception was thrown while deserializing the token.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {996d31d2-0fa3-4ffe-8e82-e155c1486d33} was not found in the key ring.
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs? Could be rotating the data protection keys.

Comment: @juunas yes, the log return
ERROR 2019-02-12 13:40:09,773 [71   ] .Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery - An exception was thrown while deserializing the token.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {996d31d2-0fa3-4ffe-8e82-e155c1486d33} was not found in the key ring.

Comment: Sounds like a data protection key issue yeah. Check out the docs on Data Protection here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.2. There's a bunch of options how to configure it, where to store keys etc. In your case it looks like the publish is destroying the keys, so you'll want to change how it is storing them.

Comment: More on configuring data protection here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2.

Comment: @juunas oh yes, thank you!!! you are right!!! please answer my question so I can mark as answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error it sounds like your Data Protection keys have rotated on publish.
Check out the docs on Data Protection here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.2.
There's a bunch of options how to configure it, where to store keys etc.
You'll want to change how it is storing them.

More on configuring Data Protection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2.